# Implement bias neurons neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent, bias-neuron

I implemented bias units for my neural network with gradient descent. But I'm not 100% sure If I've implemented it the right way. Would be glade if you can quickly look through my code. Only the parts with

> if bias:

are important.

And my second question:
Shouldn't the derivate of the softmax function be 1-x, because x is the output of the softmax function?
I tried my net with 1-x but its performance was worse.

Every help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import time
import math

class FeedForwardNetwork():

    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, dropout=False, dropout_prop=0.5, bias=False):
        np.random.seed(1)
        self.input_layer = np.array([])
        self.hidden_layer = np.array([])
        self.output_layer = np.array([])
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.dropout_prop = dropout_prop
        self.bias = bias

        r_input_hidden = math.sqrt(6 / (input_dim + hidden_dim))
        r_hidden_output = math.sqrt(6 / (hidden_dim + output_dim))

        #self.weights_input_hidden = np.random.uniform(low=-r_input_hidden, high=r_input_hidden, size=(input_dim, hidden_dim))
        #self.weights_hidden_output = np.random.uniform(low=-r_hidden_output, high=r_hidden_output, size=(hidden_dim, output_dim))

        self.weights_input_hidden = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(input_dim, hidden_dim))
        self.weights_hidden_output = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(hidden_dim, output_dim))

        self.validation_data = np.array([])
        self.validation_data_solution = np.array([])

        self.velocities_input_hidden = np.zeros(self.weights_input_hidden.shape)
        self.velocities_hidden_output = np.zeros(self.weights_hidden_output.shape)

        if bias:
            self.weights_bias_hidden = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=((1, hidden_dim)))
            self.weights_bias_output = np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=((1, output_dim)))
            self.velocities_bias_hidden = np.zeros(self.weights_bias_hidden.shape)
            self.velocities_bias_output = np.zeros(self.weights_bias_output.shape)

    def _tanh(self, x, deriv=False):
        #The derivate is: 1-np.tanh(x)**2; Because x is already the output of tanh(x) 1-x*x is the correct derivate.
        if not deriv:
            return np.tanh(x)
        return 1-x*x

    def _softmax(self, x, deriv=False):
        if not deriv:
            return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
        return 1 - np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)

    def set_training_data(self, training_data_input, training_data_target, validation_data_input=None, validation_data_target=None):
        """Splits the data up into training and validation data with a ratio of 0.85/0.15 if no validation data is given.
        Sets the data for training."""
        if len(training_data_input) != len(training_data_target):
            raise ValueError(
                'Number of training examples and'
                ' training targets does not match!'
            )
        if (validation_data_input is None) and (validation_data_target is None):
            len_training_data = int((len(training_data_input)/100*85//1))
            self.input_layer = training_data_input[:len_training_data]
            self.output_layer = training_data_target[:len_training_data]
            self.validation_data = training_data_input[len_training_data:]
            self.validation_data_solution = training_data_target[len_training_data:]
        else:
            self.input_layer = training_data_input
            self.output_layer = training_data_target
            self.validation_data = validation_data_input
            self.validation_data_solution = validation_data_target

    def save(self, filename):
        """Saves the weights into a pickle file."""
        with open(filename, "wb") as network_file:
            pickle.dump(self.weights_input_hidden, network_file)
            pickle.dump(self.weights_hidden_output, network_file)

    def load(self, filename):
        """Loads network weights from a pickle file."""
        with open(filename, "rb") as network_file:
            weights_input_hidden = pickle.load(network_file)
            weights_hidden_output = pickle.load(network_file)

        if (
            len(weights_input_hidden) != len(self.weights_input_hidden)
            or len(weights_hidden_output) != len(self.weights_hidden_output)
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                'File contains weights that does not'
                ' match the current networks size!'
            )        
        self.weights_input_hidden = weights_input_hidden
        self.weights_hidden_output = weights_hidden_output

    def measure_error(self, input_data, output_data):
        return 1/2 * np.sum((output_data - self.forward_propagate(input_data))**2)
        #return np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-output_data*np.log(self.forward_propagate(input_data))-(1-output_data)*np.log(1-self.forward_propagate(input_data))))

    def forward_propagate(self, input_data, dropout=False):
        """Proceds the input data from input neurons up to output neurons and returns the output layer.
           If dropout is True some of the neurons are randomly turned off."""
        input_layer = input_data
        self.hidden_layer = self._tanh(np.dot(input_layer, self.weights_input_hidden))
        if self.bias:
            self.hidden_layer += self.weights_bias_hidden
        if dropout:
            self.hidden_layer *= np.random.binomial([np.ones((len(input_data),self.hidden_dim))],1-self.dropout_prop)[0] * (1.0/(1-self.dropout_prop))
        if self.bias:
            return self._softmax((np.dot(self.hidden_layer, self.weights_hidden_output) + self.weights_bias_output).T).T
        else:
            return self._softmax(np.dot(self.hidden_layer, self.weights_hidden_output).T).T
        #return self._softmax(output_layer.T).T

    def back_propagate(self, input_data, output_data, alpha, beta, momentum):
        """Calculates the difference between target output and output and adjusts the weights to fit the target output better.
           The parameter alpha is the learning rate.
           Beta is the parameter for weight decay which penaltizes large weights."""
        sample_count = len(input_data)
        output_layer = self.forward_propagate(input_data, dropout=self.dropout)
        output_layer_error = output_layer - output_data
        output_layer_delta = output_layer_error * self._softmax(output_layer, deriv=True)
        print("Error: ", np.mean(np.abs(output_layer_error)))
        #How much did each hidden neuron contribute to the output error?
        #Multiplys delta term with weights
        hidden_layer_error = output_layer_delta.dot(self.weights_hidden_output.T)

        #If the prediction is good, the second term will be small and the change will be small
        #Ex: target: 1 -> Slope will be 1 so the second term will be big
        hidden_layer_delta = hidden_layer_error * self._tanh(self.hidden_layer, deriv=True)
        #The both lines return a matrix. A row stands for all weights connected to one neuron.
        #E.g. [1, 2, 3] -> Weights to Neuron A
        #     [4, 5, 6] -> Weights to Neuron B
        hidden_weights_gradient = input_data.T.dot(hidden_layer_delta)/sample_count
        output_weights_gradient = self.hidden_layer.T.dot(output_layer_delta)/sample_count
        velocities_input_hidden = self.velocities_input_hidden
        velocities_hidden_output = self.velocities_hidden_output

        self.velocities_input_hidden = velocities_input_hidden * momentum - alpha * hidden_weights_gradient
        self.velocities_hidden_output = velocities_hidden_output * momentum - alpha * output_weights_gradient

        #Includes momentum term and weight decay; The weight decay parameter is beta
        #Weight decay penalizes large weights to prevent overfitting
        self.weights_input_hidden += -velocities_input_hidden * momentum + (1 + momentum) * self.velocities_input_hidden
        - alpha * beta * self.weights_input_hidden / sample_count
        self.weights_hidden_output += -velocities_hidden_output * momentum + (1 + momentum) * self.velocities_hidden_output
        - alpha * beta * self.weights_hidden_output / sample_count

        if self.bias:
            velocities_bias_hidden = self.velocities_bias_hidden
            velocities_bias_output = self.velocities_bias_output
            hidden_layer_delta = np.sum(hidden_layer_delta, axis=0)
            output_layer_delta = np.sum(output_layer_delta, axis=0)
            self.velocities_bias_hidden = velocities_bias_hidden * momentum - alpha * hidden_layer_delta
            self.velocities_bias_output = velocities_bias_output * momentum - alpha * output_layer_delta

            self.weights_bias_hidden += -velocities_bias_hidden * momentum + (1 + momentum) * self.velocities_bias_hidden
            - alpha * beta * self.weights_bias_hidden / sample_count
            self.weights_bias_output += -velocities_bias_output * momentum + (1 + momentum) * self.velocities_bias_output
            - alpha * beta * self.weights_bias_output / sample_count

    def batch_train(self, epochs, alpha, beta, momentum, patience=10):
        """Trains the network in batch mode that means the weights are updated after showing all training examples.
           alpha is the learning rate and patience is the number of epochs that the validation error is allowed to increase before aborting.
           Beta is the parameter for weight decay which penaltizes large weights."""
        #The weight decay parameter is beta
        validation_error = self.measure_error(self.validation_data, self.validation_data_solution)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.back_propagate(self.input_layer, self.output_layer, alpha, beta, momentum)
            validation_error_new = self.measure_error(self.validation_data, self.validation_data_solution)
            if  validation_error_new < validation_error:
                validation_error = validation_error_new
            else:
                patience -= 1
                if patience == 0:
                    print("Abort Training. Overfitting has started! Epoch: {0}. Error: {1}".format(epoch, validation_error_new))
                    return
            print("Epoch: {0}, Validation Error: {1}".format(epoch, validation_error))
            self.save("Network_Mnist.net")

    def mini_batch_train(self, batch_size, epochs, alpha, beta, momentum, patience=10):
        """Trains the network in mini batch mode, that means the weights are updated after showing only a bunch of training examples.
           alpha is the learning rate and patience is the number of epochs that the validation error is allowed to increase before aborting."""
        validation_error = self.measure_error(self.validation_data, self.validation_data_solution)
        sample_count = len(self.input_layer)
        epoch_counter = 0
        for epoch in range(0, epochs*batch_size, batch_size):
            epoch_counter += 1
            self.back_propagate(self.input_layer[epoch%sample_count:(epoch%sample_count)+batch_size],
                                self.output_layer[epoch%sample_count:(epoch%sample_count)+batch_size], alpha, beta, momentum)
            validation_error_new = self.measure_error(self.validation_data, self.validation_data_solution)
            if  validation_error_new < validation_error:
                validation_error = validation_error_new
                patience = 20
            else:
                patience -= 1
                if patience == 0:
                    print("Abort Training. Overfitting has started! Epoch: {0}. Error: {1}".format(epoch_counter, validation_error_new))
                    return
            print("Epoch: {0}, Validation Error: {1}".format(epoch_counter, validation_error))
            self.save("Network_Mnist.net")            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #If the first row is a one the first output neuron should be on the second off
    x = np.array([  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
                    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0] ])

    y = np.array([ [0, 1],
                  [0, 1],
                  [1, 0],
                  [1, 0],
                  [0, 1],
                  [1, 0],
                   [1, 0],
                   [1, 0] ])

    #x = np.array([  [0, 0, 1, 1] ])
    #y = np.array([[0]]).T

    a = FeedForwardNetwork(input_dim=5, hidden_dim=200, output_dim=2, bias=False)
    a.set_training_data(x, y)
    start = time.time()
    a.batch_train(epochs=2000, alpha=0.05, beta=0.0001, momentum=0.99, patience=20)
    print(time.time()-start)
```

Comment: The definition of the bias nodes seems ok. Are you having trouble there?

Comment: When I use it like that with MNIST data I get an np.exp overflow...

Comment: With the bias nodes? That sounds rather like something with the softmax, no?

Comment: Yep with the softmax but only with bias nodes

Answer (score 0):

**In relation with the derivatives...**

If you are using the `tanh` activation function, i.e. [the derivative is:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Derivatives) `y' = 1 - y^2`. The `tanh` is commonly used because it is zero-centered.

If you are using the logistic equation, then [the derivative is:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) `y' = y(1+y)`. The softmax has a [similar derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Artificial_neural_networks).

The nice thing is that all these can be expressed as functions of themselves, so you need to have a look at the `def _softmax(self, x, deriv=False)` function, to define it in a similar way than `def _tanh(self, x, deriv=False)`.

Comment: Yes the derivate is: 1 - np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0). But the parameter x that I pass to _softmax() is equal to: np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0) so I could write 1-x. Or am I wrong?

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541930/how-to-implement-the-softmax-derivative-independently-from-any-loss-function) and the link to crossvalidated on the first answer.