# numpy : calculate the derivative of the softmax function

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation, softmax

I am trying to understand `backpropagation` in a simple 3 layered neural network with `MNIST`.

There is the input layer with `weights` and a `bias`.  The labels are `MNIST` so it's a `10` class vector.

The second layer is a `linear tranform`. The third layer is the `softmax activation` to get the output as probabilities.

`Backpropagation` calculates the derivative at each step and call this the gradient.

Previous layers appends the `global` or `previous` gradient to the `local gradient`.  I am having trouble calculating the `local gradient` of the `softmax`

Several resources online go through the explanation of the softmax and its derivatives and even give code samples of the softmax itself

```
def softmax(x):
    """Compute the softmax of vector x."""
    exps = np.exp(x)
    return exps / np.sum(exps)
```

The derivative is explained with respect to when `i = j` and when `i != j`.  This is a simple code snippet I've come up with and was hoping to verify my understanding:

```
def softmax(self, x):
    """Compute the softmax of vector x."""
    exps = np.exp(x)
    return exps / np.sum(exps)

def forward(self):
    # self.input is a vector of length 10
    # and is the output of 
    # (w * x) + b
    self.value = self.softmax(self.input)

def backward(self):
    for i in range(len(self.value)):
        for j in range(len(self.input)):
            if i == j:
                self.gradient[i] = self.value[i] * (1-self.input[i))
            else: 
                 self.gradient[i] = -self.value[i]*self.input[j]
```

Then `self.gradient` is the `local gradient` which is a vector.  Is this correct? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: This is so unclear... What gradient are you actually trying to compute? SM is a map from R^n to R^n so you may define n^2 partial derivatives dSM[i]/dx[k]...

Comment: @JulienBernu I have updated the question.  Any thoughts?

Comment: These two links helped me in understanding these https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/  + https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028029/429476
(and they are referenced in multiple places ex https://e2eml.school/softmax.html)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am assuming you have a 3-layer NN with `W1`, `b1` for is associated with the linear transformation from input layer to hidden layer and `W2`, `b2` is associated with linear transformation from hidden layer to output layer. `Z1` and `Z2` are the input vector to the hidden layer and output layer. `a1` and `a2` represents the output of the hidden layer and output layer. `a2` is your predicted output. `delta3` and `delta2` are the errors (backpropagated) and you can see the gradients of the loss function with respect to model parameters.

[image]
[image]

This is a general scenario for a 3-layer NN (input layer, only one hidden layer and one output layer). You can follow the procedure described above to compute gradients which should be easy to compute! Since another answer to this post already pointed to the problem in your code, i am not repeating the same.

Comment: To clarify one more thing.  If we were to start with z2, i.e. z1 never existed, would that make it a 2 layer NN?  The linear transform happening twice makes it a 3 layer NN?

Comment: Can you explain the names of the layers in your equations? The input layer in your case is z1? How many hidden layers and what are they?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! God bless you and good luck in your PhD studies!

Comment: I'm going to update this library I'm putting together to match the above.  https://github.com/autojazari/xiaonet/blob/master/xiaonet.py  Will edit the question once finished

Comment: What is the loss function here?

Comment: @sidmontu: I believe its cross-entropy.

Comment: Is it really correct to call the nodes in the hidden layer "activation units" when a1 = z1? There's no activation function in that layer, it's linear.

Answer (score 17):

As I said, you have `n^2` partial derivatives.

If you do the math, you find that `dSM[i]/dx[k]` is `SM[i] * (dx[i]/dx[k] - SM[i])` so you should have:

```
if i == j:
    self.gradient[i,j] = self.value[i] * (1-self.value[i])
else: 
    self.gradient[i,j] = -self.value[i] * self.value[j]
```

instead of

```
if i == j:
    self.gradient[i] = self.value[i] * (1-self.input[i])
else: 
     self.gradient[i] = -self.value[i]*self.input[j]
```

By the way, this may be computed more concisely like so (vectorized):

```
SM = self.value.reshape((-1,1))
jac = np.diagflat(self.value) - np.dot(SM, SM.T)
```

Comment: Ok so that is the Jacobian?

Comment: I think I have another disconnect.  Is the linear transform in @wasi's answer the hidden layer?

Comment: I guess so. Note that most people consider the last linear transform + the SM as only one layer. In general a layer is a linear transform followed by a non linearity (sigmoid, tanh, SM, relu, or whatever...)

Comment: In some implementations I saw, the output value of the softmax in the forward propagation was also being used. In your version that is not the case, only the input from the gradient of the loss function is being used. Am I missing  something or is this the full formula?

Answer (score 14):

`np.exp` is not stable because it has Inf.
So you should subtract maximum in `x`.

```
def softmax(x):
    """Compute the softmax of vector x."""
    exps = np.exp(x - x.max())
    return exps / np.sum(exps)
```

If `x` is matrix, please check the softmax function in [this notebook](https://github.com/rickiepark/ml-learn/blob/master/notebooks/5.%20multi-layer%20perceptron.ipynb).

Comment: Would subtracting the max value change the softmax derivative? And if not, why not?