# Python - Neural Network from Scratch using NumPy - Need help in Softmax

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

**The post looks long but it's really not, its because I am bad at explaining things :)**

---

I am trying to make a NN which classifies `O` and `X` letters. Each letter is `6x6` pixels(36 inputs), I max pooled the letters to `2x2` pixels(4 inputs) using Convolutional layer. In my NN architecture I had only 1 output Node, if the output is close to `0` then the letter is **"O"**, if it is closer to `1` then the letter is **"X"**.

- **First NN Architecture:**

[image]

My training data for the first NN Architecture:

```
x= [[0.46931818, 0.44129729, 0.54988949, 0.54295118], #O Letter Max Pooled from 6x6 to 2x2
[0.54976771, 0.54295118, 0.50129169, 0.54988949]] #X Letter Max Pooled from 6x6 to 2x2

y=[[0],[1]]
```

As you see above, **the label for O letter** is zero and **the label for X letter is 1**. So if the output is closer to 0 then it classifies the input as `O Letter`, if it is closer to 1 then it classifies the input as `X Letter`.
This was working fine for me, but when I decided to change my architecture to 2 outputs I started having problems, so I read about Softmax and I think I am implementing it wrong. Here is a photo of my new NN:

- **Second NN Architecture**

[image]

Here are my questions:

**1. Should I change my `y` variable which is `y=[[0],[1]]` because I
think my new architecture is not classifying it as if its close to 0
or 1 since each letter has its own output node.**

**2. How will my code know that the `o1` node is for O letter and the
`o2` node is for X Letter**

**3. Am I implementing the yPred right in my code while feedforwarding?
In the first architecture I had my y_pred like this: `y_pred = o1`
because I had only 1 output node. Should I send the o1 and o2 as a
victor to the softmax function and get the highest value? (*I really
think I am approaching this wrong*) here is the code I wrote:**

```
        sum_o1 = (self.w9 * h1 + self.w10 * h2)
        o1 = sigmoid(sum_o1)
        sum_o2 = (self.w11 * h1 + self.w12 * h2)
        o2 = sigmoid(sum_o2)

        #Check this later, might be implemented wrong ######################
        y_pred = softmax([o1, o2])
        y_pred = max(y_pred)
```

The reason I think I implemented it wrong because my `loss rate` sometimes gets higher and sometimes it doesnt change even after `40000` epochs! Here is how I check my loss:

```
if epoch % 1000 == 0:
        y_preds = np.apply_along_axis(self.feedforward, 1, data)
        loss = mse_loss(all_y_trues, y_preds)
        print("Epoch %d loss: %.3f" % (epoch, loss))
```

4. **In the first NN architecture, I used to calculate the partial
   derivate like this: `d_L_d_ypred = -2 * (y_true - y_pred)`, how
   should I calculate it with me new architecture? because now I don't
   think my y_true will be 0 and 1 anymore. Because I already have 2
   nodes (o1 and o2) and each stands for a letter.**

I know that I have some misunderstandings because I am a beginner, but I hope someone can explain this to me.

Even tho I have no hope of someone answering this(Since this is how stackoverflow works sometimes and it annoys me), but helps are really really appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

NOTE: Adding the code to make my question about the shapes problem more clear:

```
class OurNeuralNetwork:
  def __init__(self):
    # Weights for h1 (First Node in the Hidden Layer)
    self.w1 = np.random.normal()
    self.w2 = np.random.normal()
    self.w3 = np.random.normal()
    self.w4 = np.random.normal()
    # Weights for h2 (Second Node in the Hidden Layer)
    self.w5 = np.random.normal()
    self.w6 = np.random.normal()
    self.w7 = np.random.normal()
    self.w8 = np.random.normal()

    # Biases in the hidden layer
    self.b1 = np.random.normal() #First Node
    self.b2 = np.random.normal() #Second Node

    self.w9 = np.random.normal()
    self.w10 = np.random.normal()
    self.w11 = np.random.normal()
    self.w12 = np.random.normal()


  def testForward(self, x):
    h1 = sigmoid(self.w1 * x[0] + self.w2 * x[1] + self.w3 * x[2] + self.w4 * x[3] + self.b1)
    h2 = sigmoid(self.w5 * x[0] + self.w6 * x[1] + self.w7 * x[2] + self.w8 * x[3] + self.b2)
    o1 = sigmoid(self.w9 * h1 + self.w10 * h2)
    o2 = sigmoid(self.w11 * h1 + self.w12 * h2)
    output = softmax([o1, o2])
    return output


  def feedforward(self, x):
    h1 = sigmoid(self.w1 * x[0] + self.w2 * x[1] + self.w3 * x[2] + self.w4 * x[3] + self.b1)
    h2 = sigmoid(self.w5 * x[0] + self.w6 * x[1] + self.w7 * x[2] + self.w8 * x[3] + self.b2)
    o1 = sigmoid(self.w9 * h1 + self.w10 * h2)
    o2 = sigmoid(self.w11 * h1 + self.w12 * h2)
    output = softmax([o1, o2])
    return output

  def train(self, data, all_y_trues):

    learn_rate = 0.01
    epochs = 20000

    for epoch in range(epochs):
      for x, y_true in zip(data, all_y_trues):
        #Feedforward
        sum_h1 = self.w1 * x[0] + self.w2 * x[1] + self.w3 * x[2] + self.w4 * x[3] + self.b1
        h1 = sigmoid(sum_h1)

        sum_h2 = self.w5 * x[0] + self.w6 * x[1] + self.w7 * x[2] + self.w8 * x[3] + self.b2
        h2 = sigmoid(sum_h2)

        sum_o1 = (self.w9 * h1 + self.w10 * h2)
        o1 = sigmoid(sum_o1)
        sum_o2 = (self.w11 * h1 + self.w12 * h2)
        o2 = sigmoid(sum_o2)

        #Check this later, might be implemented wrong ######################
        y_pred = softmax([o1, o2])


        ## Partial Derivates ->
        d_L_d_ypred = -2 * (y_true - y_pred)

        # Node o1
        d_ypred_d_w9 = h1 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
        d_ypred_d_w10 = h2 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)

        #Node o2

        d_ypred_d_w11 = h1 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o2)
        d_ypred_d_w12 = h2 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o2)



        d_ypred_d_h1_o1 = self.w9 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
        d_ypred_d_h2_o1 = self.w10 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
        d_ypred_d_h1_o2 = self.w11 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o2)
        d_ypred_d_h2_o2 = self.w12 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o2)

        # Node h1
        d_h1_d_w1 = x[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)
        d_h1_d_w2 = x[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)
        d_h1_d_w3 = x[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)
        d_h1_d_w4 = x[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)
        d_h1_d_b1 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)

        # Node h2
        d_h2_d_w5 = x[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)
        d_h2_d_w6 = x[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)
        d_h2_d_w7 = x[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)
        d_h2_d_w8 = x[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)
        d_h2_d_b2 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)

        # Update weights and biases
        # Node h1
        self.w1 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1_o1 * d_h1_d_w1
        self.w2 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1_o1 * d_h1_d_w2
        self.w3 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1_o1 * d_h1_d_w3
        self.w4 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1_o1 * d_h1_d_w4
        self.b1 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h1_o1 * d_h1_d_b1

        # Node h2
        self.w5 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2_o2 * d_h2_d_w5
        self.w6 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2_o2 * d_h2_d_w6
        self.w7 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2_o2 * d_h2_d_w7
        self.w8 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2_o2 * d_h2_d_w8
        self.b2 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h2_o2 * d_h2_d_b2

        # Node o1
        self.w9 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w9
        self.w10 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w10

        #Node o2
        self.w11 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w11
        self.w12 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w12


      #Check this later after fixing the softmax issue #################################
      if epoch % 10000 == 0:
        y_preds = np.apply_along_axis(self.feedforward, 1, data)
        loss = mse_loss(all_y_trues, y_preds)
        print("Epoch %d loss: %.3f" % (epoch, loss))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Should I change my y variable which is y=[[0],[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575841/numpy-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-softmax-function)] because I think my new architecture is not classifying it as if its close to 0 or 1 since each letter has its own output node.**

**Ans** you should change from `y=[[0],[1]]` to one-hot vector likes `y=[[1,0],[0,1]]`. It mean that we want the output at index 0 (your first output node) are 1 if the input image is 0. And the output at index 1 (your second output node) are 1 if the input image is x.

**2. How will my code know that the o1 node is for O letter and the o2 node is for X Letter**

**Ans** Your model will learn from the onehot label `y=[[1,0],[0,1]]`. During model training, your model will realize that if it want to minimize the loss function, when the input image is 0, it should fire value `1` from the first output node, and vice versa.

**3. Am I implementing the yPred right in my code while feedforwarding? In the first architecture I had my y_pred like this: y_pred = o1 because I had only 1 output node. Should I send the o1 and o2 as a victor to the softmax function and get the highest value? (I really think I am approaching this wrong) here is the code I wrote:**

**Ans** During training, we do need only the probability of class `0` and `x` to do the back-propagation for updating weight. So, `y_pred = max(y_pred)` is not needed.

**4. In the first NN architecture, I used to calculate the partial derivate like this: d_L_d_ypred = -2 * (y_true - y_pred), how should I calculate it with me new architecture? because now I don't think my y_true will be 0 and 1 anymore. Because I already have 2 nodes (o1 and o2) and each stands for a letter.**

**Ans** maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575841/numpy-calculate-the-derivative-of-the-softmax-function) can help you