# Softmax and its derivative along an axis

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, derivative, softmax

I'm trying to implement a Softmax activation that can be applied to arrays of any dimension and softmax can be obtained along a specified axis.

[image]

Let's suppose I've an array `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, then if I need the softmax along the rows, I extract each row and apply softmax individually on it through `np.apply_along_axis` with `axis=1`. So for the example given above applying softmax to each of `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` we get the output as `softmax = [[0.26894142, 0.73105858], [0.26894142, 0.73105858]]`. So far so good.

Now for the backward pass, let's suppose, I'll have the gradient from the upper layer as `upper_grad = [[1,1],[1,1]]`, so I compute the Jacobian `jacobian = [[0.19661193, -0.19661193],[-0.19661193, 0.19661193]]` of shape (2,2) for each of the 1D arrays of shape (2,) in `softmax` and then `np.dot` it with the corresponding 1D  array in `upper_grad` of shape (2,), so the result of dot product will be an array of shape (2,), the final derivative will be `grads = [[0. 0.],[0. 0.]]`

I definitely know I'm going wrong somewhere, because while doing gradient checking, I get ~0.90, which is absolutely bonkers. Could someone please help with what is wrong in my approach and how I can resolve it?

```
import numpy as np


def softmax(arr, axis):
  # implementation of softmax for a 1d array
  def calc_softmax(arr_1d):
    exponentiated = np.exp(arr_1d-np.max(arr_1d))
    sum_val = np.sum(exponentiated)
    return exponentiated/sum_val
  # split the given array of multiple dims into 1d arrays along axis and
  #   apply calc_softmax to each of those 1d arrays
  result = np.apply_along_axis(calc_softmax, axis, arr)
  return result

def softmax_backward(arr, axis, upper_grad):
  result = softmax(arr, axis)
  counter = 0
  upper_grad_slices = []

  def get_ug_slices(arr_1d, upper_grad_slices):
    upper_grad_slices.append(arr_1d)

  def backward(arr_1d, upper_grad_slices, counter):
    local_grad = -np.broadcast_to(arr_1d, (arr_1d.size, arr_1d.size)) # local_grad is the jacobian
    np.fill_diagonal(local_grad, 1+np.diagonal(local_grad))
    local_grad*=arr_1d.reshape(arr_1d.size, 1)
    grads = np.dot(local_grad, upper_grad_slices[counter]) # grads is 1d array because (2,2) dot (2,)
    counter+=1 # increment the counter to access the next slice of upper_grad_slices
    return grads

  # since apply_along_axis doesnt give the index of the 1d array,
  #   we take the slices of 1d array of upper_grad and store it in a list
  np.apply_along_axis(get_ug_slices, axis, upper_grad, upper_grad_slices)

  # Iterate over each 1d array in result along axis and calculate its local_grad(jacobian)
  #   and np.dot it with the corresponding upper_grad slice
  grads = np.apply_along_axis(backward, axis, result, upper_grad_slices, counter)
  return grads


a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
result = softmax(a, 1)
print("Result")
print(result)

upper_grad = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
grads = softmax_backward(a, 1, upper_grad)
print("Gradients")
print(grads)
```

`apply_along_axis` documentation - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Comment: Please include the definition of softmax you're using as well as your code, that is an [MCVE].

Comment: hey @flawr I've added the supporting code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb. I was using the counter to get the next slice of `upper_grad`, but the counter was only getting updated locally, so this caused me to get the same slice of `upper_grad` each time, thus giving invalid gradient. Resolved it using pop method on `upper_grad_slices`

Updated code

```
import numpy as np


def softmax(arr, axis):
  # implementation of softmax for a 1d array
  def calc_softmax(arr_1d):
    exponentiated = np.exp(arr_1d-np.max(arr_1d))
    sum_val = np.sum(exponentiated)
    return exponentiated/sum_val
  # split the given array of multiple dims into 1d arrays along axis and
  #   apply calc_softmax to each of those 1d arrays
  result = np.apply_along_axis(calc_softmax, axis, arr)
  return result

def softmax_backward(arr, axis, upper_grad):
  result = softmax(arr, axis)
  upper_grad_slices = []

  def get_ug_slices(arr_1d, upper_grad_slices):
    upper_grad_slices.append(arr_1d)

  def backward(arr_1d, upper_grad_slices):
    local_grad = -np.broadcast_to(arr_1d, (arr_1d.size, arr_1d.size)) # local_grad is the jacobian
    np.fill_diagonal(local_grad, 1+np.diagonal(local_grad))
    local_grad*=arr_1d.reshape(arr_1d.size, 1)
    grads = np.dot(local_grad, upper_grad_slices.pop(0)) # grads is 1d array because (2,2) dot (2,)
    return grads

  # since apply_along_axis doesnt give the index of the 1d array,
  #   we take the slices of 1d array of upper_grad and store it in a list
  np.apply_along_axis(get_ug_slices, axis, upper_grad, upper_grad_slices)

  # Iterate over each 1d array in result along axis and calculate its local_grad(jacobian)
  #   and np.dot it with the corresponding upper_grad slice
  grads = np.apply_along_axis(backward, axis, result, upper_grad_slices)
  return grads


a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
result = softmax(a, 1)
print("Result")
print(result)

upper_grad = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
grads = softmax_backward(a, 1, upper_grad)
print("Gradients")
print(grads)
```